# Ошабка при исполнении кода в браузере ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Я написал такой код

```html
@using Shop.Data.Mosels
@model IEnumerable<Car>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Сотрудники</p>
    @{
        foreach (var car in Model)
        {
            <div>
                <h2>Имя: @car.nameCar</h2>
            </div>
        }
    }
</body>
</html>
```

на браузере выводит ошибку

```html
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

AspNetCore.Views_Cars_List.<ExecuteAsync>b__8_1() in List.cshtml, line 17

Stack Query Cookies Headers

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_Cars_List.<ExecuteAsync>b__8_1() in List.cshtml

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Сотрудники</p>
@{

foreach (var car in Model)

{
<div>
<h2>Имя: @car.nameCar</h2>
</div>
}
}

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
AspNetCore.Views_Cars_List.ExecuteAsync() in List.cshtml

@using Shop.Data.Mosels
@model IEnumerable<Car>
@{

Layout = null;

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
```

Что не так в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, Вы не передали в представление модель. Или передали `null`.